# query to update exp in dayabase by +1 on every click

Tags: mysql, pdo

This is the code i am trying to use so when someone presses "click me" it updates the players exp by +1 everytime. It allows me to press but doesnt update the database etc.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$rpg = "UPDATE members SET exp = exp + 1 WHERE `memberID`='{$id}'";
$prepStatement = $db->prepare( $rpg );
$prepStatement->execute(array($id => 1));
}

<form method ="post">
<input type="submit" value="click me"/>
</form>
```

I would like so when someone presses "click me" they get +1 exp added to "exp" in database.

Answer (score 1):

You are not preparing your query properly - the way you are doing it has no parameters, but then you are passing one in the query, so you will get a parameter count mismatch error. The correct code should be:

```
$rpg = "UPDATE members SET exp = exp + 1 WHERE `memberID`=:id";
$prepStatement = $db->prepare( $rpg );
$prepStatement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

Comment: Hello, this doesn't seem to update anything either :/

Comment: How is the `$id` variable being set?

Comment: $id = (int) (isset($_GET['memberID']) ? $_GET['memberID'] : $_SESSION['memberID'] );

Comment: Since you are using `POST`, `$_GET['memberID']` will not be set. Have you checked that `$_SESSION['memberID']` is set and valid?

Comment: So are you seeing any errors? Why are you executing the update inside a while loop?

Comment: i am not seeing any errors no, it literally just isn't updating the database when i press "click me" http://prntscr.com/nfzevm

Comment: @danchy19 I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I can't see any issue with your code and without access to your system it's impossible for me to debug.

Comment: I built a small db myself and the code works fine. Are you sure the form is submitting? Some browsers won't submit a form with no `action` attribute.

Comment: i'm not an extremely experienced coder when you say an "action"  attribute what do you mean?

Comment: where you have `<form method="post'>` typically that would have an `action="xxx.php"` atttribute as well.